# React router CSS for all routes

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <NavigationBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Root} />
        <Route path="/Path1" component={Path1} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

How can I give all the components (`Root`, `Path1`) a 15% left and right margin, but not the navigation bar, without applying it individually in each of the routes?

I have tried applying the style to Switch and a div that wraps the Switch but none of these worked (see CodeSandbox).

[image: Edit wnj89opn5w]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the Switch with a div and apply the styles to it. For example:

```
<div style={styles}><Switch>....</Switch><div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The routes get built in the following structure:

```
<div id="root">
  <div>
    <nav>
    <div>Route</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As such, you can target the routes specifically with:

```
#root > div > div {
  margin: 0 15%;
}
```

Note the use of `>`. This is known as the **[child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)**, and only targets the immediate children. This means that only `<div>` elements that are a direct child of `<div>` elements, which in turn are a direct child of `#root`, will be targetted.

I've created an updated version showcasing this **[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wnnj7n4qkk)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

When facing problem like this, use the point-and-click inspector tool (⌘ + shift + C).

Upon inspecting, you will see your navbar structure to be this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="/">Route1</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="/Route2">Route2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

So to target all the `<li>`, you can simply do

```
.nav>li {
  margin: 0 15%
}
```

Or `.nav>li>a` if you intend want to apply directly onto the link.

---

#### CSS Specificity Score

Something that you **must** understand in order to write predictable CSS and avoid scenario like this all together!

For example. let's say if after applying the margin as above, you do this:

```
li {
  margin: 0;
}
```

You would realize this style wouldn't get applied at all due to lower specificity score.

`.nav > li` has a `class` and an `element`.

`li` only has an `element`, hence lower score.

It's something really simple to understand but unfortunately not so many people know about.

[5 min read to understand CSS Specificity Score](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)